# Error el leer un csv con polars

Tags: python

Hola estoy tratando de leer un CSV con polars pero me lanza el siguiente error :

```
ComputeError: could not parse `3122806977 - 3122885930` as dtype `i64` at column 'Teléfono' (column number 11)

The current offset in the file is 57933 bytes.

You might want to try:
- increasing `infer_schema_length` (e.g. `infer_schema_length=10000`),
- specifying correct dtype with the `dtypes` argument
- setting `ignore_errors` to `True`,
- adding `3122806977 - 3122885930` to the `null_values` list.

Original error:  bytes non-empty
```

El codigo que estoy usando es

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.read_csv("datos_abiertos.csv")
df.head(2)
```

Ya inspeccione el CSV y en la columna donde me lanza el error hay numeros de telefonos separados por un guion, como podria manejar este error, gracias por su ayuda

El CSV eta disponble en datos abierto de colombia en https://www.datos.gov.co/Inclusi-n-Social-y-Reconciliaci-n/PUNTOS-DISTRIBUCI-N-BIENESTARINA-ICBF/crxh-as6c/about_data

tiene esta visual

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hola podrias proporcionar el CSV que te esta dando el error es principalmente para poder ejecutar el archivo como tu y a si ver en que estas fallando en un teatro de pruebas. En caso de que sea privado el CSV crea una copia del original y modifcalo un poco

Comment: Hola proporcione el enlace a la informacion es un dataset de datos abiertos colombianos, no hay problema con los datos. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polars por defecto lee 100 lineas del csv (se puede modificar con el argumento `infer_schema_length`) con la finalidad de inferir los tipos de cada columna. En tu caso, supongo que al menos las primeras 100 filas contendrán un solo numero en la columna *Teléfono*, por lo que polar infiere que esa columna es de tipo entero.

El problema viene cuando tras inferir el tipo se encuentra luego con una fila que en la columna *Teléfono* tiene varios números, como es el caso de `3122806977 - 3122885930`, lo cual no puede parsearse como un entero y lanza la excepción.

Las soluciones posibles te las da la propia excepción, pero en tu  caso solo una es viable a priori, especificar el tipo de dato para esa columna como cadena de texto (`polars.Utf8`):

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.read_csv("datos_abiertos.csv", dtypes = {"Teléfono": pl.Utf8}) # o str
df.head(2)
```

Dependiendo de lo que hagas luego con esos datos, también es posible que te interese convertir esa columna en una lista de enteros (`polars.List(Int64)`), en vez de una cadena de texto, en cuyo caso puedes hacer algo como:

```
import polars as pl

df = (pl.read_csv("datos_abiertos.csv", dtypes={"Teléfono": pl.Utf8})
        .with_columns(pl.col("Teléfono")
        .str.extract_all(r"\d+")
        .cast(pl.List(pl.Int64))))
df.head(2)
```

---

**Edición**

Ahora que has proporcionado el csv, podemos ver que efectivamente hasta la fila 338 la columna *Teléfono* tiene un solo numero, si especificas a polars que extienda las filas a usar para inferir el tipo de datos hasta esa fila (o mas), inferirá `Utf8` en vez de `Int64` y no tendrás la excepción:

```
df = pl.read_csv("datos_abiertos.csv", infer_schema_length=338)
```

pero creo que mejor ser explicito e indicarle directamente el tipo adecuado.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias estaba experimentando con polars, es un detalle del cual no estaba enterado,  en efecto esto soluciono el problema

Answer (score 0):

Se me a ocurrido una solución

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.read_csv("datos_abiertos.csv", dtypes=str)
```

Si te fijas se le esta diciendo a panda que los datos csv van a estar entre comillas y no en otro tipo de formato por ejemplo podria estar en numeros o en binario en caso de lo que lo tengas en numero tansolo tendras que cambiar el str a int debido a que int es el tipo de variable que almacenan los numeros.

Si no te resuelve no dudes en comentar

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu aporte, lo maneje como me indicaste pero me dice que el tipo debe ser una lista o un diccionario, intente con pl.str al parecer polars ya lo actualizo, la solucion definitiva fue una combinacion con tu respuesta, añadiendo un diccionario con el tipo de dato para esa columna

Comment: Si al tener varios valores de diferente estilo lo más correcto es usar utf-8 como bien dijo FjSevilla utf-8 engloba los simbolos que tenemos en el teclado otra forma como tu has dicho es definiendo un diccionario con la estructura de csv pero esa no es muy buena solucion debido a que metes muchas lineas de codigo de forma inecesaria.
Nota aun que utf-8 no siempre es la solucion mas optima de ahi la importancia de que entiendas cuando es str, int, list y dict hhay más pero estos tres son los más comunes en el siguiente comentario te explico cuando usar cada cosa

Comment: [explicacion str, int y Boolean](https://keepcoding.io/blog/tipos-de-variables-en-python/) aqui explican bien esos tres tipos en nuestro caso se aplicaria a si
{"Telefono" : 12345678} seria {"Telefono" : int} por eso en caso querer leer este diccionario lo ideal seria con el codigo de la respuesta sustituit con int
{"Telefono": '123456789'} seria {"Telefeno" : str} seria tal cual el codigo de la respuesta en caso de que sea {"Telefono" : [123456789, '122346789']} seria {"Telefono" : list} por lo que cambiarias str por list y por ultimo {"Telefono" : {"Pepe" : '123456789'}} cambiarias a dict

Comment: te lo he explicaso a detalle debido a que pone que eres nuevo en caso de que ya sepas como funciona el almacenamiento en python no hace falta que te lo leas